# How to get variables passed through jquery.load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a page 'index.html' with a jquery load method like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var user = 10;

    $('#content").load('profile.html', { id: user });
});
```

My issue is how to get this variable *id* in the page 'profile.html'.

Thank you.

Comment: what is the use of variable in html code???

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  The variable `id` will be POST'd to the profile.html page.

Comment: you dont pass to html.... but to i.e. php:  `$('#content").load('profile.php?id=user');`

Comment: php is not an option cause it isn't installed in the server im working

Comment: So what are you trying to do with the `id`?

Comment: i want to get the var id to put it in a URL to use an getJSON, then get the data from the json and put the content in 'profile.html'

Comment: And how are you doing the `getJSON`?

Comment: fyi, your quotation marks are invalid. `'#content"` should be `'#content'` or `"#content"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By supplying data to the `load()` call, you're sending that data via a `POST` request to the server.

As such, on the server side if you want to use that variable, you need to access the variable `id` from the `POST` data. Without knowing what language you're using for your server side, I can't help you further.